# Unauthorized error while connecting Object Storage from API from Postman

Tags: api, restful-authentication, postman, ibm-cloud-infrastructure, object-storage

I am trying to get object storage container details using provided API in post man But I am getting Unauthorized error,

API information available at
http://developer.openstack.org/api-ref/object-storage/index.html?expanded=get-object-content-and-metadata-detail,show-account-details-and-list-containers-detail#accounts

Following details I am set in PostMan,

**Method** Get

**Url:** https://{domain}.objectstorage.softlayer.net/auth/v1.0/{userid}?format=json

**Header:** 
  Key:  X-Auth-Token
  Value: {token}

Error got in response of PostMan,

```
<html>
    <h1>Unauthorized</h1>
    <p>This server could not verify that you are authorized to access the document you requested.</p>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To retrieve containers from Object Storage using **Postman**, follow these steps:

### 1. We need to generate the token to access Object Storage

You need to get credentials from your object storage, so you can go to:

> [Control Portal](https://control.softlayer.com) >> Object Storage >>
>   Select Account Name (e.g. SLOS123123-10) >> Select Cluster (e.g. Milan
>   1) >> click on "View Credentials"

You will be able to see

- "Authentication Endpoint (public and private)"
- "username"
- "API Key (Password)"

Then, you can go to postman and fill as the below example:

[image]

As you see, I had success with the request. So I need the "**Headers**" information from the response, as the follow example:

[image]

### 2. Retrieve containers

After getting "**X-Storage-Url**" and "**X-Storage-Token**", you can retrieve the containers as the example below:

[image]

I hope it helps you to access Object Storage using Postman, please let me know any doubt or comment.

Comment: there is one interesting question for you.. How to create Object in Object Storage Using JAVA?                                                             http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40720973/how-to-create-object-in-object-storage-using-java

Comment: I have been already answered this question in your post:

[How to create Object in Object Storage Using JAVA?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40720973/how-to-create-object-in-object-storage-using-java)

Let me know any doubt or comment in that thread please

Answer (score 0):

Are you using your SoftLayer username or the Object Storage username? To get your Object Storage credentials go to https://control.softlayer.com/storage/objectstorage > Click on your Object Storage Username and on the following page click View Credentials.

Get the Token

`curl -i -H "X-Auth-Key: [insert API Key here]" -H "X-Auth-User: [insert Object Storage Username here]" [insert Authentication Endpoint here]`

Once you have the Token you can perform basic operations

List Containers 

`curl -i -H 'X-Auth-Token: [X-Auth-Token from Authentication step]' [X-Storage-Url from Authentication step]`

View Objects in a Container

`curl -i -H "X-Auth-Token: [X-Auth-Token from Authentication step]" [X-Storage-Url from Authentication step]/[container name]`

Answer (score 0):

To start, the error that you're receiving is because the userid parameter in your request is not correct. The X-Storage-Url should be placed in that position.

To retrieve the containers you first need a X-Auth-Token and a X-Storage-Url. For this you could run the next curl command:

```
curl -i -H "X-Auth-User: ACC-278436-15:USERNAME " -H "X-Auth-Key: API_KEY " https://dal05.objectstorage.softlayer.net/auth/v1.0
```

**ACC-278436-15:** The object storage username retrieved from SoftLayer_Account::getHubNetworkStorage method

**USERNAME:** The username used in Control portal which is the same used in the REST request that calls the SoftLayer_Account::getHubNetworkStorage method

**API_KEY:** The apikey used in the REST request that calls the SoftLayer_Account::getHubNetworkStorage method

The result will be similar to this:

•   X-Auth-Token: AUTH_tkb26239d441d6401d9482b004d45f7259 – the token we need

•   X-Storage-Url: https://dal05.objectstorage.softlayer.net/v1/AUTH_df0de35c-d00a-40aa-b697-2b7f1b9331a6 - the URL to access the storage

Now place these values in this way:
[image]

Here's a good link on how to manage SoftLayer Object Storage through rest API
https://sldn.softlayer.com/blog/waelriac/managing-softlayer-object-storage-through-rest-apis