# How to create Object in Object Storage Using JAVA?

Tags: java, ibm-cloud-infrastructure, object-storage

I know how to create object by get authenticate and than call API

Here below link is information available how to get authenticate,
[Unauthorized error while connecting Object Storage from API from Postman](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40319729/unauthorized-error-getting-while-get-container-details-from-object-storage-api-i)

Is there any library available in JAVA to perform these operation?

I got library from below link but it seems old one and not working,
https://github.com/softlayer/softlayer-object-storage-java/tree/master/sl-objectstorage

If anyone know Can you please post how to operate it?

By using library getting below error,

```
Error while handling an HTTP client call
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.restlet.data.Parameter incompatible with org.restlet.data.Header
    at org.restlet.engine.header.HeaderUtils.addExtensionHeaders(HeaderUtils.java:220)
    at org.restlet.engine.header.HeaderUtils.addRequestHeaders(HeaderUtils.java:479)
    at org.restlet.engine.adapter.ClientAdapter.toSpecific(ClientAdapter.java:163)
    at org.restlet.engine.adapter.HttpClientHelper.handle(HttpClientHelper.java:118)
    at org.restlet.Client.handle(Client.java:153)
    at org.restlet.routing.Filter.doHandle(Filter.java:150)
    at org.restlet.routing.Filter.handle(Filter.java:197)
    at org.restlet.resource.ClientResource.handle(ClientResource.java:1092)
    at org.restlet.resource.ClientResource.handleOutbound(ClientResource.java:1176)
    at org.restlet.resource.ClientResource.handle(ClientResource.java:1047)
    at org.restlet.resource.ClientResource.handle(ClientResource.java:1023)
    at org.restlet.resource.ClientResource.handle(ClientResource.java:928)
    at org.restlet.resource.ClientResource.get(ClientResource.java:636)
    at com.softlayer.objectstorage.Client.httpRequest(Client.java:245)
    at com.softlayer.objectstorage.Client.get(Client.java:177)
    at com.softlayer.objectstorage.Client.auth(Client.java:128)
    at com.softlayer.objectstorage.Client.<init>(Client.java:107)
    at com.softlayer.objectstorage.Container.<init>(Container.java:77)
    at com.wrakafka.consumer.ObjectStorageUtil.createContainer(ObjectStorageUtil.java:24)
    at spark.KafkaConsumer.main(KafkaConsumer.java:51)

Nov 21, 2016 1:24:18 PM org.restlet.resource.ClientResource retry
INFO: A recoverable error was detected (1002), attempting again in 2000 ms.
Nov 21, 2016 1:24:20 PM org.restlet.engine.adapter.HttpClientHelper handle
INFO: Error while handling an HTTP client call
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.restlet.data.Parameter incompatible with org.restlet.data.Header
    at org.restlet.engine.header.HeaderUtils.addExtensionHeaders(HeaderUtils.java:220)
    at org.restlet.engine.header.HeaderUtils.addRequestHeaders(HeaderUtils.java:479)
    at org.restlet.engine.adapter.ClientAdapter.toSpecific(ClientAdapter.java:163)
    at org.restlet.engine.adapter.HttpClientHelper.handle(HttpClientHelper.java:118)
    at org.restlet.Client.handle(Client.java:153)
    at org.restlet.routing.Filter.doHandle(Filter.java:150)
    at org.restlet.routing.Filter.handle(Filter.java:197)
    at org.restlet.resource.ClientResource.handle(ClientResource.java:1092)
    at org.restlet.resource.ClientResource.retry(ClientResource.java:1650)
    at org.restlet.resource.ClientResource.handle(ClientResource.java:1100)
    at org.restlet.resource.ClientResource.handleOutbound(ClientResource.java:1176)
    at org.restlet.resource.ClientResource.handle(ClientResource.java:1047)
    at org.restlet.resource.ClientResource.handle(ClientResource.java:1023)
    at org.restlet.resource.ClientResource.handle(ClientResource.java:928)
    at org.restlet.resource.ClientResource.get(ClientResource.java:636)
    at com.softlayer.objectstorage.Client.httpRequest(Client.java:245)
    at com.softlayer.objectstorage.Client.get(Client.java:177)
    at com.softlayer.objectstorage.Client.auth(Client.java:128)
    at com.softlayer.objectstorage.Client.<init>(Client.java:107)
    at com.softlayer.objectstorage.Container.<init>(Container.java:77)
    at com.wrakafka.consumer.ObjectStorageUtil.createContainer(ObjectStorageUtil.java:24)
    at spark.KafkaConsumer.main(KafkaConsumer.java:51)

Nov 21, 2016 1:24:20 PM org.restlet.resource.ClientResource retry
INFO: A recoverable error was detected (1002), attempting again in 2000 ms.
Nov 21, 2016 1:24:22 PM org.restlet.engine.adapter.HttpClientHelper handle
INFO: Error while handling an HTTP client call
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.restlet.data.Parameter incompatible with org.restlet.data.Header
    at org.restlet.engine.header.HeaderUtils.addExtensionHeaders(HeaderUtils.java:220)
    at org.restlet.engine.header.HeaderUtils.addRequestHeaders(HeaderUtils.java:479)
    at org.restlet.engine.adapter.ClientAdapter.toSpecific(ClientAdapter.java:163)
    at org.restlet.engine.adapter.HttpClientHelper.handle(HttpClientHelper.java:118)
    at org.restlet.Client.handle(Client.java:153)
    at org.restlet.routing.Filter.doHandle(Filter.java:150)
    at org.restlet.routing.Filter.handle(Filter.java:197)
    at org.restlet.resource.ClientResource.handle(ClientResource.java:1092)
    at org.restlet.resource.ClientResource.retry(ClientResource.java:1650)
    at org.restlet.resource.ClientResource.handle(ClientResource.java:1100)
    at org.restlet.resource.ClientResource.retry(ClientResource.java:1650)
    at org.restlet.resource.ClientResource.handle(ClientResource.java:1100)
    at org.restlet.resource.ClientResource.handleOutbound(ClientResource.java:1176)
    at org.restlet.resource.ClientResource.handle(ClientResource.java:1047)
    at org.restlet.resource.ClientResource.handle(ClientResource.java:1023)
    at org.restlet.resource.ClientResource.handle(ClientResource.java:928)
    at org.restlet.resource.ClientResource.get(ClientResource.java:636)
    at com.softlayer.objectstorage.Client.httpRequest(Client.java:245)
    at com.softlayer.objectstorage.Client.get(Client.java:177)
    at com.softlayer.objectstorage.Client.auth(Client.java:128)
    at com.softlayer.objectstorage.Client.<init>(Client.java:107)
    at com.softlayer.objectstorage.Container.<init>(Container.java:77)
    at com.wrakafka.consumer.ObjectStorageUtil.createContainer(ObjectStorageUtil.java:24)
    at spark.KafkaConsumer.main(KafkaConsumer.java:51)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can only upload files using: [Softlayer Object Storage Java Client](https://github.com/softlayer/softlayer-object-storage-java) (it's not possible to create objects), here an example for authentication, create container and upload a file using the client:

```
package com.softlayer.objectstorage.main;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import com.softlayer.objectstorage.Container;
import com.softlayer.objectstorage.ObjectFile;


public class ObjectStorage {
    String baseUrl;
    String user;
    String password;

    public ObjectStorage(String baseUrl, String user, String password){
        this.baseUrl = baseUrl;
        this.user = user;
        this.password = password;
    }

    public void createContainer(String containerName){

        try{
            Container containerCreate = new Container(containerName, baseUrl, user,
                    password, true);
            containerCreate.create();

        }catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }

    public void UploadFile(String containerName, String fileName, String path)
    {
        try{
            ObjectFile oFile = new ObjectFile(fileName, containerName, baseUrl, user, password, true);
            Map<String, String> tags = new HashMap<String, String>();
            tags.put("testtag", "Test Value");
            String newOb = oFile.uploadFile(path, tags);
        }catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println(e);
        }


    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        /**
         * Define Object Storage's parameters
         */
        String baseUrl = "https://dal05.objectstorage.softlayer.net/auth/v1.0/";
        String user = "set me";
        String password = "set me";

        // Define the container name to create
        String containerName = "containerTest";
        // Define the file name to create in the object storage
        String fileName = "newTest.txt";
        // Define the location path from file that you wish to upload
        String pathFile = "C:\\Users\\Ruber Cuellar\\Documents\\test.txt";

        // Create Object Storage connection
        ObjectStorage objectStorage = new ObjectStorage(baseUrl, user, password);
        // Create Container
        objectStorage.createContainer(containerName);
        // Upload file
        objectStorage.UploadFile(containerName, fileName, pathFile);

    }
}
```

I hope it helps, let me know any doubt or comment

Comment: It seems to run this code required to add dependencies for org.restlet.jee. Is it possible to use Class file and some how not require this dependencies?

Comment: As I see, the Client needs these dependencies

Comment: Okay. How can save String(Base64 encoded string) into object storage. Code it seems for upload file only

Comment: Unfortunately, its not possible to create objects using [Softlayer Object Storage Java Client](https://github.com/softlayer/softlayer-object-storage-java) , you can only upload files. Some customers recommend to use [jclouds](https://github.com/jclouds/jclouds)

Issue: [Deprecate this library](https://github.com/softlayer/softlayer-object-storage-java/issues/3)

My apologies for the inconveniences

Comment: or you can try with another programming language binding for Object Storage:

[An Introduction to Object Storage](http://sldn.softlayer.com/article/Introduction-Object-Storage#Language_Bindings)

Comment: So do mean I can not save string in container using available java libraries?

Comment: Unfortunately no, you can only upload files

Comment: I got error updated in Question. Can you please confirm version of depedencies?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128641/discussion-between-vimal-dhaduk-and-ruber-cuellar).