# Upload video in SOFTLAYER(IBM Cloud)

Tags: ios, objective-c, video, xcode7, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I have to upload video in SOFTLAYER(IBM Cloud) server using Objective C. I'm using xcode7.2 with Objective C. I don't have any idea how to upload video in cloud base server using Objective C. When go to [SOFTLAYER API](http://www.softlayer.com/api) link there is no guideline for iOS or how to implement SOFTLYAER using Objective C. My question is how to integrate SOFTLAYER in Xcode and how to implement this.

I'm adding an screen shot of [SOFTLAYER guide](http://sldn.softlayer.com/) there is no guide for iOS.[image: SOFTLAYER GUIDE IMAGE]

If any one upload video in SOFTLAYER server using Objective C or if You have any idea about this please help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Found a Github link(https://github.com/softlayer?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=&type=&language=objective-c) for SOFTLAYER Messaging service. But cannnot found any softlayer-object-storage for iOS. just like this ( https://github.com/softlayer?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=&type=&language=php ). If anyone have any useful link for softlayer-object-storage in iOS please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes as you wrote all the Softlayer clients are here:

https://github.com/softlayer

However there is not a specific client to manage object storage using objective-c, But you can manage Softlayer's object storage using simple rest requests and be able to upload your video successfully, I am pretty sure that Objective-C provides an API to deal with REST request.

you can see here a guide about manage Object Storage using rest here:

https://sldn.softlayer.com/blog/waelriac/managing-softlayer-object-storage-through-rest-apis

Let me know if you have more questions

Regards

Comment: Thanks @Nelson for your valuable help. This will be very helpful for me. I'm implementing that. Is there any sample code for this type of video uploading. I'm found this link (http://sldn.softlayer.com/article/REST). Is both link same?

Comment: the links are from softlayer, but the one in your comment is about how to use REST with other Sofltayer's services. about examples related to video I am affraid to tell you that I've never seen a softlayer example about that. However Softlayer's object storage is based in Open Stack, so maybe there are examples of upload videos for Open Stack.

Comment: Also perhaps these links can help you, they are related to upload large files to open stack, the same idea works with Softlayer: http://docs.openstack.org/user-guide/cli-swift-large-object-creation.html http://docs.openstack.org/developer/swift/overview_large_objects.html

Comment: Thanks @Nelson for your help. when i'm calling this api in rest client (https://USERID:API_KEY@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_Account/getHubNetworkStorage) with "USERID" and "API_KEY" giving me error "401 Unauthorised". This also giving me a json error
 {
  "error": "Access Denied. ",
  "code": "SoftLayer_Exception_Public"
}

Comment: for that service you do not have to use the userID, you need to use the API user , to see the API credentials go to https://control.softlayer.com -> users ->clicl on your user->see api username and apikey

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Nelson for this link [Softlayer Object Storage access through rest api](https://sldn.softlayer.com/blog/waelriac/managing-softlayer-object-storage-through-rest-apis). From this link we can upload video in object storage directly from app. For more details you see this link [Access Softlayer using Postman](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40319729/unauthorized-error-getting-while-get-container-details-from-object-storage-api-i/40349997).

I'm uploading video in softlayer object storage using rest api calling. I'm calling rest api using AFNetworking in objective C. Here are the following simple steps:-

My authToken is:- "AUTH_tk9eafc199756fabe8066f"

1) Get "auth token" and "x-storage-url" from softlayer object storage server. You can get this by using "Authentication Endpoint (public and private)" this api. Sending your "username" and "API Key (Password)" in header field.

```
-(void)callRestAPI{

NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://sjc01.objectstorage.softlayer.net/auth/v1.0/"];
AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];
manager.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];
manager.requestSerializer =  [AFHTTPRequestSerializer serializer];
[manager.requestSerializer setValue:@"HJYBOS984353-3:ghym8435" forHTTPHeaderField:@"X-Auth-User"];
[manager.requestSerializer setValue:@"26704dbc93e5c39986da451e539857f6596dc9be18aad7a6b4dc2822f48e66f8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"X-Auth-Key"];
[manager GET:URL.absoluteString parameters:nil progress:nil success:^(NSURLSessionTask *task, id responseObject) {

    NSHTTPURLResponse *response = ((NSHTTPURLResponse *)[task response]);
    NSDictionary *headers = [response allHeaderFields];
    authURL = [headers valueForKey:@"X-Storage-Url"];
    authToken = [headers valueForKey:@"X-Auth-Token"];
    NSLog(@"\nHeader Token:: %@ \n Header URL:: %@ \n",authToken,authURL);

    [PMCommonClass userDefaultValueSave:authToken key:SOFTLAYER_AUTH_TOKEN];
    [PMCommonClass userDefaultValueSave:authURL key:SOFTLAYER_AUTH_URL];

    NSDictionary *mainDict = [PMCommonClass jsonDictionaryFromResponse:responseObject];
    NSLog(@"Main Dict:: %@",mainDict);
} failure:^(NSURLSessionTask *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error:: %@", error.localizedDescription);
}];
}
```

2) After that from that "auth token" and "x-Storage-url" we can created container in object storage.

```
-(void)createConatiner{
NSString *authUrl = @"https://sjc01.objectstorage.softlayer.net/v1/AUTH_695d079a-ead3-4045-b303-a1b123acdb3db";
NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/Container6",authUrl]];
AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];
manager.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];
manager.requestSerializer =  [AFHTTPRequestSerializer serializer];
[manager.requestSerializer setValue:authToken forHTTPHeaderField:@"X-Auth-Token"];
[manager PUT:URL.absoluteString parameters:nil success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nonnull task, id  _Nullable responseObject) {
    NSHTTPURLResponse *response = ((NSHTTPURLResponse *)[task response]);
    NSDictionary *headers = [response allHeaderFields];
    NSLog(@"Header Dict:: %@",headers);
    if ([response statusCode] == 201) {
        //Successfully container created
    }else{
        //Some problem occure
    }

    } failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nullable task, NSError * _Nonnull error) {
    NSLog(@"Error:: %@", error.localizedDescription);
}];}
```

3)At last upload video in container using "Auth token" and "x-Storage-url" with bellow code

```
-(void)uploadFileInContainer{
NSString *authUrl = @"https://sjc01.objectstorage.softlayer.net/v1/AUTH_695d079a-ead3-4045-b303-a1b123acdb3db";
//Get Video From Document Directory
NSError *error = nil;
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *videoFilePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingFormat:@"/vid10.mp4"];

//Convert video url to NSData
NSData *videoData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:videoFilePath options:NSDataReadingMappedIfSafe error:&error];
if (videoData != nil ) {

    if ([PMCommonClass isNetworkRechable]) {

        NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/Container5/Video4.mp4",authUrl];
        NSMutableURLRequest *request  = [[AFHTTPRequestSerializer serializer] requestWithMethod:@"PUT" URLString:urlString parameters:nil error:nil];
        [request setValue:authToken forHTTPHeaderField:@"X-Auth-Token"];
        [request setValue:@"video/mp4" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
        [request setValue:@"video/mp4" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];

        NSURLSessionConfiguration *configuration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
        AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [[AFHTTPSessionManager alloc]initWithSessionConfiguration:configuration];

        NSURLSessionUploadTask *uploadTask = [manager uploadTaskWithRequest:request fromData:videoData progress:^(NSProgress * _Nonnull uploadProgress) {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                NSLog(@"UPLOAD Progress==>%f",uploadProgress.fractionCompleted*100);
            });
        } completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse * _Nonnull response, id  _Nullable responseObject, NSError * _Nullable error) {
            if (error) {
                NSLog(@"Error: %@", error.localizedDescription);
            } else {
                NSLog(@"Success: %@ %@", response, responseObject);
            }
        }];
        [uploadTask resume];
    }
}}
```

4) Then download this uploaded object from object storage container using same process.

```
-(void)getObject{
NSString *authUrl = @"https://sjc01.objectstorage.softlayer.net/v1/AUTH_695d079a-ead3-4045-b303-a1b123acdb3db";
NSString *authToken = @"AUTH_tk9eafc199756fabe8066f";
NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/Container5/Video4.mp4",authURL]];
AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];
manager.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];
manager.requestSerializer =  [AFHTTPRequestSerializer serializer];
[manager.requestSerializer setValue:authToken forHTTPHeaderField:@"X-Auth-Token"];
[manager.requestSerializer setValue:@"video/mp4" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[manager.requestSerializer setValue:@"video/mp4" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
[manager GET:URL.absoluteString parameters:nil progress:nil success:^(NSURLSessionTask *task, id responseObject) {

    NSHTTPURLResponse *response = ((NSHTTPURLResponse *)[task response]);
    NSDictionary *headers = [response allHeaderFields];
    NSLog(@"Header Dict:: %@",headers);

    //NSLog(@"Response OBJ:: %@",responseObject);
    //UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:responseObject];
    //NSLog(@"uiiamge %@",image);


    NSData *videoData = responseObject;
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *tempPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingFormat:@"/video1026.mp4"];
    BOOL success = [videoData writeToFile:tempPath atomically:NO];
    if (success) {
        NSLog(@"save Path is:: %@",tempPath);
    }

} failure:^(NSURLSessionTask *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error:: %@", error.localizedDescription);
}];}
```

That's the following step for upload and download video from softlayer object storage.